# Tornado & Thread-safe websocket handler

Tags: python, websocket, thread-safety, multiprocessing, tornado

I'm developping a web socket application using Tornado.
I need to handle simultenous connections and be able to process requests in parallel.

Yes, by default Tornado isn't thread-safe, so I have to do it by myself in my application.
The documentation doesn't say a lot on thread-safe websocket handlers, so I'd like to ask some feed-back from you who have already experimented with it.

**UPDATE**
Here is a minimal piece of code describing the problem:

handler.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re, zmq, json, sys, time
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from tornado.options import define, options


define("port", default=9000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

clients = []


class JobProgressHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self, *args):
        if self not in clients:
            clients.append(self)

        self.stream.set_nodelay(True)        

    def on_message(self, script_uid):
        print 'Starting verbose for : ', script_uid
        self.send_progress(script_uid)

    def on_close(self):
        print 'Closing: ', self
        if self in clients:
            clients.remove(self)

    def send_progress(self, script_uid):
        """
        Send a fake job progress
        """
        for x in xrange(10):
            self.write_message(json.dumps({script_uid: (x+1)*10}))
            #time.sleep(1)
            print script_uid, (x+1)*10
```

server.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tornado.web
from tornado.options import options, parse_command_line
from handler import JobProgressHandler


app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/jobprogress', JobProgressHandler),
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_command_line()
    app.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

test.js (tests in browser's console)

```
function websock(script_name)
{
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/jobprogress");
    ws.onopen = function(){ws.send(script_name); console.log("Socket opened");};
    ws.onmessage = function (evt){console.log(evt.data);};
    ws.onclose = function(){console.log("Connection is closed ...");};
}


websock('diagnostics.eth0');
websock('diagnostics.eth1');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need threads?  The reason tornado is not thread-safe is because it is designed for event-driven concurrency within a single thread; you don't need threads to support many simultaneous connections.  If you do combine threads with tornado you need to be very careful about the handoff between threads since nearly all tornado methods can only be safely called from the IOLoop thread.

Comment: What do you mean by "manage"?  There's an example here: https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket/chatdemo.py

Comment: I mean that I don't want to queue websocket connections, but work in parallel with each client. Actually my server has the same logic as the example you suggest me. In fact on each following connection the server starts to respond one time the previous has exited. I want to manage connections simultaneously.

Comment: The example I linked supports many simultaneous connections; if you're only seeing responses after the previous connection has closed then you're doing something wrong and blocking the IOLoop.

Comment: Ben Darnell, I updated my question with a simple example which reproduces the problem. I have tested the chat example, but in first sight it is difficult to so say if the messages are comming in parallel or in sequence as their weight is too small. Will try to retest it with a sleep.

Comment: @ScotchAndSoda They are, of course, NOT being executed in parallel. The writing/reading to the IO sockets can intermingle with one another. Remember, execution on one "socket" can continue while your server is waiting on IO from another.

Comment: @ScotchAndSoda this thread just got bumped and I see that you've added a time.sleep call to the handler code.  Code that runs on the Tornado IOLoop must be non-blocking.  Use IOLoop.add_timeout instead of time.sleep() for time-based delays, and anything else that takes a significant amount of time must either be converted to a non-blocking style or moved off to a thread pool.

Comment: @Zoran,how could I "execute" while my server waiting on IO from another? That what I'm really interested in

Comment: @Ben Darnell, please do not focus on "time.sleep()" which is representative and it is not the core of the problem! You can try my example without it and you will conclude the same thing as I did, i.e: the "diagnostics.eth1" socket will start to receive data after the "diagnostics.eth0" has finished.

Comment: @Ben Darnell, Why ? I need that my TWO clients, "diagnostics.eth0" and "diagnostics.eth1" process independently, which does not seem to work as expected!

Comment: @Ben Darnell, I do not want to queue socket connections, but treat them simultaneously! Is it possible with Tornado as I actually do this with ws4py? I have the sentiment that my question has not been enough clear, am I wrong?

Comment: Tornado's concurrency model does not involve threads; to process requests concurrently you must write the code in a non-blocking style (callbacks or coroutines, etc).  You cannot write synchronous blocking code in Tornado the way you would with a thread-oriented concurrency model.  As i said in my previous message, whatever time-consuming process time.sleep is standing in for must be either rewritten to be non-blocking or shipped off to a thread pool.

Comment: @ScotchAndSoda As BenDarnell said. You need to off-load your heavy processing to another thread, or server for that matter. You also need to understand that the for loop in your code is very important. You are never "releasing" execution back to the main IO loop so that Tornado can receive a new connection. I'll add info in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the code below, you add a callback in the IOLoop telling it to run your method, when it can. It will then update the WS client, and add another callback for itself to execute 1 second later. As far as I know the time specified may not be the exact time taken.

What it essentially does is it tells the IOLoop "go ahead and process other events, and in about 1 second, can you call my function". The other events I mention above could be anything. It could be servicing new open connection requests from other WS clients, it could be other callbacks to update their handlers, etc.

On a side note, I strongly suggest you read up a little on Python async concepts and programming.

Note, the code below wasn't tested, but it should work fine. Let me know if you have to make alterations to get it working.

```
from functools import partial
import datetime

def send_update(self, script_uid, max=10):
    self.write_message(json.dumps({script_uid: (script_uid+1)*10}))
    if script_uid > max:
        return
    io_loop.add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=1), partial(self.send_update, script_uid + 1))
```